# PHP application single sign on with ADFS

Tags: php, single-sign-on, adfs

I am planning to integrate my php application with ADFS for single sign on

So here is the flow

1. The user will open the domain of my app if he is not already signed in i will redirect it to sso url provided in the metadata.xml file shared with me by the AD team.
2. Once he is redirected to the AD login once the users fills the login page the request would come to my application

1st Question :-

( How is this going to happen ?? ) Do i need to provide to the url to the AD

2nd Question :-

What would be the request type, structure going to be

3rd Question :-

How is the application going to validate whether the user is authenticated or not. ?

Answer (score 0):

you should be getting the integration document form AD Team, from [this help disk](https://www.okta.com/blog/2018/06/what-is-adfs/) the workflow will be as follows

1. The user navigates to a URL provided by the ADFS service.
2. The ADFS service then authenticates the user via the organization’s AD service.
3. Upon authenticating, the ADFS service then provides the user with an authentication claim.
4. The user’s browser then forwards this claim to the target application, which either grants or denies access based on the Federated Trust service created.

as per the 4th point, user will be returned with the claim(must be some tokens) to federation, using that you should validate the user again from ADFS,.

> Noe: read-out the documents that you got from ADFS

Comment: What i have been given by the AD team is the federationmetadata.xml file I think from this I would be extracting the SSO url and Logout url right ?

Comment: Hope u don't have an Integration doc, better you could request them to send a integration document they might need to know abt your platform and all to provide, but I just Google ed it for the doc check if it is useful https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/adfs-sso-guide/

Comment: Exactly i don't have the integration Doc. and what all things should be required in this doc. so that I can ask the same, The above link that is provided its a pretty much standard of another application and it will differ from app to app. so what are the basic things in the doc. which are required ?

Comment: The basic first thing to integrate with any 3rd party application you should ask for a integration doc,
and then if the app require any additional needs(in this case probably we don't know right now) may be once we start integration at that time we might need some salt key value pair to authenticate us with ADFS

Comment: What i have gone through is the Auth0 its a standard solution that is third party integration SSO I think this would be ideal in my case to use it..

Comment: Yup - Auth0 is a good solution and then federate with ADFS. You could do exactly the same thing with simpleSAMLphp.

Comment: @sarthakkapoor ya **auth** fn will give you idea how the 3rd party integrations are working but if you need to integrate the **ADFS** then you should follow their instruction,.